# SVN: diff not showing effect of merge

Tags: svn

I'm apparently not understanding SVN.

I'm at revision 15140:

```
$ svn info
Revision: 15140

$ svn diff -r 15092:HEAD MyFile.pm
Index: MyFile.pm
===================================================================
--- MyFile.pm   (revision 15092)
+++ MyFile.pm   (revision 15140)
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@

 sub myMethod {
     my ( $self, $args ) = @_;
-
+    
     my $prog_obj = $self->prog_obj;
     my $session  = $prog_obj->session;
```

Now I don't like that my revision contains the worthless whitespace modification, so I want to get rid of that change entirely.

```
svn merge -c 15092 MyFile.pm
svn commit -m "Removing whitespace update"
svn update
```

Now if I do the diff again, it should be gone, right?

```
$ svn diff -r 15092:HEAD MyFile.pm
Index: MyFile.pm
===================================================================
--- MyFile.pm   (revision 15092)
+++ MyFile.pm   (revision 15140)
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@

 sub myMethod {
     my ( $self, $args ) = @_;
-
+    
     my $prog_obj = $self->prog_obj;
     my $session  = $prog_obj->session;
```

Nope.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to do:

`svn merge -c -15092 MyFile.pm`

Note the minus before the revision number, which specifies this is a reverse merge.

Trying to merge a revision on a branch (or trunk) that was committed directly to that branch (or trunk) doesn't do anything.

Your commit command then does nothing because there's nothing to commit.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work for me either, and I eventually gave up